# The value from Datalist is undefined, Datalist is generated by ajax

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

I have one select and one datalist html.
The Select lists several states such as NY or NJ.
The Datalist lists school names. This is generated by ajax <-> php because school names depend on the state.

However, when I call the value of Datalist, the return is undefined.

```
form id="search_school">
<strong>Select State:</strong>
<select id="selectState" onchange="selectState()">
    <option value="NA" >         </option>
    <option value="NJ" >New Jersey</option>
    <option value="NY">New York</option>
</select>
    <div id="test"></div>
    <div id="displaySchools"></div>

<input id="searchBTN" type="button" value="Search"/><br>
</form>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#selectState').change(function(){
    var selectState = $('#selectState').val();

    if(selectState != '')
    {
        $.ajax({
        url:"selectState.php",
        method:"POST",
        data:{selectState:selectState},
        success:function(data)
        {
            $("#displaySchools").html(data);
}
            });
        }
        else
        {
            alert("All Fields are required");
        }
    });
});
```

This part is the problem. I also did GetElementById but still returns undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var contents = $('#schools');
    $("#searchBTN").click(function(){
    $("#test").html(contents);`
});
});

selectState.php
$selectState = $_POST['selectState'];
switch ($selectState) {
case "NJ":
    $msg='<strong>Enter School:</strong>
        <input list="schools"  name="schools">
        <datalist id="schools">
            <option value="New Jersey Institute of Technology"></option>
            <option value="Rutgers University"></option>
            <option value="Princeton University"></option>
        </datalist>';
    echo $msg;
    break;
case "NY":
    $msg='<input list="schools"  name="schools">
        <datalist id="schools">
            <option value="Columbia University"></option>
            <option value="Cornell University"></option>
            <option value="New York University"></option>
        </datalist>';
    echo $msg;
    break;
default:
    echo "error";
}
```

The result in chrome developer tool looks like there is no problem.

```
<div id="displaySchools">                           
<strong>Enter School:</strong>
    <input list="schools" name="schools">
    <datalist id="schools">
    <option value="New Jersey Institute of Technology"></option>
    <option value="Rutgers University"></option>
    <option value="Princeton University"></option>
</datalist>
</div>
```

Comment: I don't really understand your problem. The code part you say is the issue is executed at document.ready, and therefore before any schools are loaded, so it's normal it returns undefined (at that time, there is no element with id #schools).

Answer (score 0):

I gave input tag name and id and used that to display school name.

```
    $selectState = $_POST['selectState'];
    switch ($selectState) {
    case "NJ":
        $msg='<strong>Enter School:</strong>
            <input list="schools"  name="schools" name="schoolName" id="schoolName">
            <datalist id="schools">
                <option value="New Jersey Institute of Technology"></option>
                <option value="Rutgers University"></option>
                <option value="Princeton University"></option>
            </datalist>';
        echo $msg;
        break;
    case "NY":
        $msg='<input list="schools"  name="schools" name="schoolName" id="schoolName">
            <datalist id="schools">
                <option value="Columbia University"></option>
                <option value="Cornell University"></option>
                <option value="New York University"></option>
            </datalist>';
        echo $msg;
        break;
    default:
        echo "error";
    }
```

And then jquery would be:

```
            $("#searchBTN").click(function(){
            var schoolName = $('#schoolName').val();
            $("#test").html(schoolName);
            });
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. The problem was the 'id'. This is my first time using Datalist. I misplaced the id. It should be in the input, not datalist